# Why is my assembly code to find the largest number not working?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, dosbox

I am very new to assembly programming and honestly, this is the first code I ever wrote in computer (for assembly).

The largest number is clearly '9' but it's showing some character (not available in keyboard). Why so? thnx.

```
    .model small
.stack 64
.data
   array db 2,5,6,3,9,8
   count db 7
 large db ?
.code
   main proc far
   start:
      mov ax,@data
      mov ds,ax
      lea si, array
      mov dl,[si]
      mov large, dl
      inc si
      dec count
   l1:
      mov al,[si]
      cmp al,large
      jg largefound
   nochange:
      inc si
      dec count
      cmp count,00h
      jnz l1

   largefound:
      mov large,al
      inc si
      dec count
      cmp count,00h
      jnz l1

mov dl,large
add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: You can't expect to write source in Assembly, compile and run it, and see it working (I admit it sometimes happen to ME... after ~20 years of ASM coding ... SOMETIMES). Even if it runs and outputs correct result, it's more than likely there's some part of the code working in different way than you expected. You should always open new code in debugger and step over it instruction by instruction, verifying every assumption  used during writing. Many will be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with your program :

- The counter is set too high. Set it to **1 less than the number of elements in the array**. This way you don't need the first `dec count`.
- The program flow is chaotic, meaning you loose track of what is does and are doing too much.

Instead of using 2 separate blocks of code that also replicate several instructions, you would better use the opposite conditional jump to by-pass the setting of a new largest value:

```
  lea  si, array
  mov  al, [si]      ;First element
  mov  large, al
l1:
  inc  si
  mov  al, [si]      ;Next elements
  cmp  al, large
  jng  NotLarger
  mov  large, al     ;New largest element
NotLarger:
  dec  count
  jnz  l1
```

Note that you don't need to write `cmp count, 0` because the `dec count` instruction already sets the necessary flags for the operation of the `jnz l1`.

Note how you no longer need the separate `inc si` by just moving the *l1* label one line up.

Study this example and see how much smaller and more efficient the code is!

Answer (score 1):

You have 6 values in array, yet count is 7. Also look at what happens when count becomes zero in nochange block. It drops through to largefound. It should jump past it instead.

Comment: although, it said avoid comments like '+1' or 'thnx', thanks anyways. (first time stackoverflow user)

Comment: @gataers You're welcome.  Use upvotes if the information is useful to express thanks and eventually select the best answer by accepting it.